# Does binary code need legal protection?

Tags: contract-law, software

Firstly, sorry if this is not the right tag.

I have recently come in contact with a person through social media and we are discussing a business opportunity.

This person is working in networking and cloud business with algorithms. The main discussion was if I could modify an algorithm that I wrote and made publicly available under LGPL several years ago, to run on a different platform. That is something I've done and I keep the modified version of the code private at the moment.

Now for the legal matters, for our discussion to go further I would need to share the compiled code for testing and if it is approved after testing, then I would be asked to share my source code with the person and his company.

Long story short...

1. What is the best way to deal with sharing compiled binaries? (Do I need some form of agreement or contract?)
2. How can I protect myself when sharing the code later? (I bet some contract...?)

Regards

Comment: It is always advisable to have a well-written contract that governs the scenarios that may arise. But your question seems too generic. It is unclear from *what* exactly you do you seek to protect yourself: licensing & commercialization, support, liabilities arising from program failures, non-compete & non-disclosure, etc.

Comment: You wrote the code, and released it under the LGPL.  Did you write all the code, or did you include somebody else's code under the LGPL?   If you are the sole copyright holder, you can do as you wish, but if it's under the LGPL you have no choice on whether to provide the source code.

Comment: The code I wrote now is completely new and is based on the one I wrote in the past. More specifically I wonder if it advisable to provide a binary (compiled code) without any contract or agreement. What I am trying to protect is both my contribution and recognition on this side project. In other words, should the company of the person I am in discussion with, benefit from my work, I would not want to be left outside.

Answer (score 2):

Code is protected by copyright - it doesn't matter the language that it is written in.

That said, you clearly need a contract if you are conducting a business relationship.